# How to display Custom error message on asp.net compilation errors

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, custom-errors

I have configured my web.config to show 'error.htm' error page when exceptions occur on the website. But I am unable to show the page when an asp.net compilation error occurs. How do I make that happen. Im running on IIS 7.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you have a compilation error on a live site?

But, without testing, I can't imagine what you are trying to do is possible.  If it can't compile it can't run any code.

Comment: In our case somebody forgot to include a third-party assembly which ended up causing a compile error so it *can* happen. :)

Comment: Then I think what I said still stands, if you can't run code.. you can't show a friendly error as it is just dead in the water.  If it is possible to do otherwise, that would be a nice find.

Answer (score -2):

set the mode attribute to On so error details will not shown to anybody.

```
<customErrors
       mode="on" 
       defaultRedirect="~/errorpage.aspx" 
/>
```

Comment: This does not work. A yellow screen is still shown and now the Error.htm. Instead of getting a Compile Error message you now just get a Runtime Error message telling you to change the customErrors.